# Best way to loop through a lot of files and zip each one separately?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I need to loop through a relatively large set of files (> 5000), zipping and uploading each one *separately* (not as directories or groups of files) to a server in turn.

The biggest part of my problem is to know which is the best way to do the zipping in terms of ease of implementation and performance. I thought there must be a standard Cocoa framework for something that is apparently a very common requirement but there doesn't seem to be any such framework.  Other suggestions and approaches I've found so far:

- [zip.framework](http://code.google.com/p/zip-framework/) at code.google.com, which "is a cocoa framework for easy zip file listing, reading and writing. The main purpose of this framework is to prevent you from having to use command line utilities in your application by providing a native Cocoa interface" - seems a lot of people have found this link (but I didn't notice anyone who had actually used it before!)
- [ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) also at code.google.com - "base on open source code 'MiniZip'".
- Suggestions about using `NSTask` to call command line utilities such as **ditto** are common, such as in this [CocoaDev question](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UsingZipFilesExamples) but I don't like the idea of having to do it
- Similarly, someone here suggested `NSTask` to call **zip** and **unzip** - but this [posting](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ZipArchiveLibraryForCocoa) says that the "only problem is that when the files are decompressed, the Mac headers have been stripped, so Mac OS dosen't recognize the file!! (i.e. I zip an application and it stripps the "appl" from the file. When I unzip it, it is unusable."
- Someone's framework called **ZipKit** [here](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home)
- [Another CocoaDev question](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ZipArchiveLibraryForCocoa) discusses several approaches e.g. creating wrapper for C++ archiving code, creating C wrapper for **zlib** and **minizip** (minizip is built around zlib), etc
- Something about [NSDataCategory](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory) (didn't understand it)
- An open-source manga/comic book reader(!) from www.feedface.com called [**FFView**](http://www.feedface.com/projects/ffview.html) which has its own separate [archiving framework](http://www.feedface.com/projects/files/ffview/FFArchive-src-0.6.tar.bz2)

The zipped files need to be unzipped in Windows.

Please, I hope someone has real-world experience with a solution that meets similar requirements to mine.  As you can see, I've already found a lot of links so just another link to another framework/approach without something that actually indicates its applicability to my problem will not really be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at wrapping whatever method you end up using in `NSOperation` objects so that the system can efficiently handle concurrency for maximum performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'd consider the "proper Cocoa way" to do it.  You may not like it, but it works, it requires no external frameworks, and it requires very little code.

Add a shell script to your application bundle, `zipmany.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
SRC="$1"
DEST="$2"
cd "$SRC"
for FILE in $(find . -not -name '.*' -a type f)
do
    zip -jD "$DEST"/"$FILE".zip "$FILE"
done
```

And then, in Cocoa,

```
NSString *script = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zipmany" ofType:@"sh"];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zipmany.sh", srcDir, destDir, nil]];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
if ([task terminationReason] == ATASK_SUCCESS_VALUE)
    succeeded;
else
    failed;
```

You may balk at this kind of stuff, but delegating this kind of task to a separate process is robust and fairly standard.

If the filenames can have spaces, you'll have to change the shell script a little bit; I considered writing the "safe" version but this is more readable.  You can also make a progress bar by echoing output from the script to be read by the application.

The call to `waitUntilExit` will cause your app to freeze or "beach ball" unless you run the entire thing in a separate thread, or know enough about Unix IPC to handle SIGCHLD.

Comment: I will try this now, thank you... but why would there be so many alternatives if this is the "proper Cocoa way"?

Comment: "Proper Cocoa Way" is inherently subjective.  But if someone asks me, "Can you zip up a thousand files for me in separate zip files?" my first thought would be, "Ah, I can do that with a shell script in five minutes."  Doing it with a framework seems like an unnecessary complication, when we already have such good tools as shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks! The main thought behind my question was, "Hmm.. what do they know that I don't?" I instinctively wanted to have everything in the core code where it can be maintained in one place and it can all be checked and compiled as a whole, but otherwise had no concrete objections.

Comment: I think the main use of the frameworks is to do things like list objects in zip files, or to read the contents of individual files.  For example, lots of games do this with their assets.  But zipping files is less interactive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Linux I would use a shell script with a few tools (zip, lftp and maybe find). Then you can zip all the files and upload then by just running the script.
I could give you some help with such a solution.

Or is it a requirement that you implement the compression tool in C or C++ using the libraries you mentioned?

**Update**

Why is Unicode relevant for your problem? Because of file names?

You could solve this problem by writing a wrapper to convert file names to
latin1 encoding, and store a small text file along with the compressed file.

Regarding efficiency, maybe you can do some research and find out what the best algorithm is and then look for a library supporting it. As far as I know, zip compression is based on lz77 or lzw: you might even look it up somewhere and implement it yourself,
it should not very difficult if you want to compress individual files because you only
need to implement the basic algorithm and apply it to a stream of bytes.
See e.g. http://en.pudn.com/downloads33/sourcecode/zip/detail106575_en.html, http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression

Comment: I am building an app using Cocoa/Objective-C for Mac OS X.  The app will perform the zipping.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I cannot help you much with that since I have never used MaxOS and Objective-C. Just one (quite spontaneous) question: why don't you try out one of the libraries yo have found already? I guess it boils down to writing a small test program and link it to the library. Then if the performance suites your needs you are quite far already.

Comment: Thanks anyway. yes, I could try out one or more of them but there are two issues, from my point of view. 1. There are so many possibilities that I think I would have to try out at least a few to feel that I've given this any sort of diligence 2. Even then, I still might not discover a particular issue until the code has gone into production e.g. with size of file, unicode characters, file types, etc. Someone having gone through this before can therefore be very valuable.