# How to optimize loop that zips and uploads files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, optimization

I am looping through an array of file paths retrieved by a core data predicate, zipping and uploading each file per iteration of the loop, about 4 or 5000 files in total.  (The technique I use for zipping is basically the one described here: [Best way to loop through a lot of files and zip each one separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527809/best-way-to-loop-through-a-lot-of-files-and-zip-each-one-separately/6528082#6528082))  Currently, I'm running the app in debug mode from Xcode.  After a little while, with each iteration of the loop, not only does the app seem to run slower, Xcode does too - indeed, my whole computer becomes less responsive.  I'm now researching general rules for efficient loops involving NSStrings, NSArrays, NSNotifications, etc but I'm also hoping someone could also point out obvious bottlenecks and inefficiencies in my code.  Although my code uses garbage collection, I tried putting in release calls with the small hope that might make a difference though my understanding is that it shouldn't.  Here is an abridged version of my code with just the important parts:

```
//Zip paths saved in Core Data and upload them to a server
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

//get path of the shell script that zips a file
NSString *zipShellScript = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"backupzipper"
                                                           ofType:@"sh"];

//get array of File managed objects related to User managed object
NSArray *filesToUpload = [User files];

//args for the shell script
//NSString *sourceFilePath = [NSString string];
//NSString *targetFilename = [NSString string];
//NSString *targetFilePath = [NSString string];

//the following appears to make a big improvement
NSString *sourceFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString string]];
NSString *targetFileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString string]];
NSString *targetFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString string]];

NSError *error;

for (File *file in filesToUpload) //loop through array of File managed objects
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    sourceFilePath = file.path;
    targetFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",
                      [[sourceFilePath lastPathComponent]
                       stringByDeletingPathExtension]]; //e.g. misc.doc will produce misc.zip

    [task setArguemnts:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:zipShellScript,
                        sourceFilePath, //full path of file to zip e.g. /Users/stifin/documents/misc.doc
                        workingDirectory, //where the zip will be placed e.g. /Users/stifin/Library/Application Support/MyApp/
                        targetFilename,  //filename after zipping e.g. misc.zip
                        nil]];
    [sourceFilePath release]; //my attempt to reduce memory usage even though this is garbage collected app
    [targetFilename release];

    [task setLaunchPath@"/bin/sh"];
    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]]; //fixes odd behaviour where NSLog no longer works after NSTask

    //do zip
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];

    if ([task terminationReason] == NSTaskTerminationReasonExit)
    {
        [task release]; //doubt this helps

        [self uploadFile:targetFilePath]; //method just sleeps for 1 sec to simulate upload time

        file.dateUploaded = [NSDate date];
        error = nil;
        if ([context save:&error])
            NSLog(@"Saved ok");
        else
            NSLog(@"Save error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        //delete zip from working directory
        [self cleanUpFile:targetFilePath];
        [targetFilePath release]; //doubt this helps

        //send notification of file processed
        info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                file.filename, @"name",
                file.sizeBytes, @"size",
                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"success",
                nil];
        [nc postnNotificationName:@"FileProcessed" object:nil userInfo:info];
        [info release]; //doubt this helps
    }
    else {
        //handle task failure
    }
}
[nc removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: I found this suggestion to ["avoid autorelease"](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-5.html). I didn't think applied to GC environment but I changed the args for shell script (in the edited code above) accordingly anyway and am surprised at the significant improvement.

Comment: Nothing wrong with autorelease as long as you understand what it's doing. I'd say "avoid autorelease in tight loops or use your own local pool, draining it every so often" would be more to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Introduction.html), -release is ignored. If you want to collect immediately, use `[[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectIfNeeded];` or, even `-collectExhaustively`. Don't do this every trip through the loop, just every hundred or so.

Of course all this assumes you've used Instruments to make sure this is the issue. You haven't said whether you've done so, which leads me to believe you're making assumptions. The problem might just be elsewhere (though I agree this is by far the most likely candidate - GC + many allocations in a tight loop needs some extra care). Not a good way to work. Measure first, *then* optimize.

Comment: thanks for this! You're correct: I haven't used instruments yet. I'm new to Mac programming so haven't yet found out what tools are used to do this. I don't actually assume what is slowing the code down and posted my code for this reason. My [string release] statements are not because I assume that they are specifically the culprits - I fully expect someone to point to something else entirely they could see in my code. However, I _do_ know that the bottleneck(s) is/are associated with this loop because everything slows down the moment execution hits this loop. Will investigate Instruments. Thx

Comment: I'm reasonably confident your gut feeling is correct because this situation will definitely cause GC resource hogging (GC isn't being allowed to run collection) but you might be surprised at other things that fall out. Instruments has GC-specific tools. Use those as well as the Time Profiler instrument.

Comment: Could you possibly edit my code with a few things that you would normally do as best practice so that I can get an idea of how the concepts actually look? I'm not asking you to assume where the bottlenecks are - just that it's easier to optimize code that already applies good practices than writing bad code and then trying to optimize it.

Comment: Just add an NSInteger counter variable (set to 0) before entering the loop. Increment the counter at the end of every loop. When the counter reaches, say, 100, reset it to zero and call the [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectIfNeeded]; code I mentioned. This way, every 100 trips through the loop, garbage collection runs, keeping your memory usage to a minimum. Really simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to speed it up create 1 thread per CPU core and divide the list up.  On any modern CPU this will increase the zipping speed by a factor of 4-8 times!

If your files are small it will also increase the upload speed a lot, since a lot of the time is spent managing the connection rather than actually sending data.

For larger files (over a few hundred Kb) or even 1 CPU core it still is useful to have at least 2 uploads going at the same time since some servers limit per connection bandwidth, and it will allow using the full upload bandwidth (something is always uploading rather than having to wait for zipping or connections to complete).